# Would the "What is your solution to the FizzBuzz problem" question belong here?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, scope

Would the [FizzBuzz question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75466/disappeared-question-and-related-answers) belong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because there's no way to objectively judge a winner.

This is quite clearly covered in [the faq](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/faq).

> All questions on this site, whether a programming puzzle or a code golf, should have …
>
> - An objective primary winning criterion, so that it is possible to indisputably decide which entry should win.
> - A clear specification of what constitutes a correct submission. Test cases are highly encouraged.

I'd also argue it's not even a contest, just another "let's make an infinite list of X!" type question, perhaps only (if you're lucky) limited by the number of different programming languages one could imagine or create.